# tess-two OCR not decoding correctly

Tags: android, tesseract, tess-two

I have followed the tutorials to get Tesseract and specifically tess-two and eyes-two installed and a part of my Android app.

It runs, but the OCR text that is returned from
`baseApi.getUTF8Text();` is  complete gibberish.

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 4;
        Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path , options);
        receipt.setImageBitmap(bmp);

        try {
            ExifInterface exif = new ExifInterface(path);
            int exifOrientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION , ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);
            int rotate = 0;
            switch (exifOrientation) {
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:    rotate =  90;    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:   rotate = 180;    break;
                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:   rotate = 270;    break;
            }
            if (rotate != 0) {
                int w = bmp.getWidth();
                int h = bmp.getHeight();
                Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
                matrix.preRotate(rotate);
                bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0, w, h, matrix, false);
            }

            bmp = bmp.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);


            TessBaseAPI baseApi = new TessBaseAPI();
            baseApi.init(DATA_PATH , "eng");
            baseApi.setImage(bmp);
            String OCRText = baseApi.getUTF8Text();
            baseApi.end();

            Log.i("OCR Text", "rotate  " + rotate);
            Log.i("OCR Text", "OCR   ");
            Log.i("OCR Text",  OCRText);
            Log.i("OCR Text", "=======================================================================================");
```

Photographing a check which has OCR characters
returns

```
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): rotate  90
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): OCR   
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): 4— ‘ ‘
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): \Dxﬁ ‘
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): I W man"! no Accounv
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): 1’
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): my... «unblm m. mm.
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): :~A
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): «Ln.
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): ‘ “w “IN. N I “H‘M‘
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): mmnwnmw- .; k. '
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): Wilt-run”. uni” nl
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): mam. I
05-14 11:01:59.131: I/OCR Text(18199): =======================================================================================
```

Any advice on how to clean up and correct the OCR recognition?
device used is a Samsung Galaxy 7".

Comment: The Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7" doesn't have autofocus on its main (rear) camera, so it's unlikely that you'll be able to get better results short of using a different device.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like

```
OCRText = OCRText.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ");
OCRText = OCRText.trim();
```

which is based on the a Tesseract implementation I found here: [SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java](https://github.com/GautamGupta/Simple-Android-OCR/blob/master/src/com/datumdroid/android/ocr/simple/SimpleAndroidOCRActivity.java)

Comment: Thanks.   But I believe it might have something to do with focus.  If I scan using the front camera (which has auto focus) it makes much more sense about 90% accurate.  When I scan using the rear camera (which does NOT have auto focus) it is the gibberish above.  Which should be a name and address.